# Angular 2 ngFor Update View Lifecycle Hook

Tags: typescript, angular, lifecycle, angular2-template

I wish to trigger an animation after I update an array of values which is bound to the template html via *ngFor.

For my animation to make sense, I need to trigger it after the view has updated with the latest values.

I was wondering if there was a point in the lifecycle I could hook into when the view is finished updating? Or if I could call something to trigger the view to immediately update with the latest values?

Answer (score 0):

> I was wondering if there was a point in the lifecycle I could hook into when the view is finished updating?

You can have a directive wrapping each element in the `ngFor`. This directive can do the animation on first render only.

Comment: Thanks for the speedy reply!

I actually need to trigger animations on the parent (& siblings of the parent) when the view finishes updating the children in the `ngFor`.

Comment: You can get a hold of the parent from the `parentNode` of the directive element

Answer (score 0):

```
  animations: [
    trigger('fadeInOutTranslate', [
      transition(':enter', [
        style({opacity:0}),
        animate(300, style({opacity:1}))
      ]),
      transition(':leave', [
        style({transform: 'translate(0)'}),
        animate(300, style({opacity:0}))
      ])
    ])
  ],
```

I didn't test it, but it works with *ngIf, so why not with *ngFor, Maybe you may find your way into angular animation property.

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/animations.html